# Pass type information at runtime

Tags: scala, casting, scala-2.10

I have a DSL and some runtime code. The problem is I got somewhere at runtime:

```
val clazz: Class[_ <: java.io.Serializable] = classOf[java.lang.String]
val value: java.io.Serializable = "abc"
```

and I have a class

```
class MyWrapper[T <: java.io.Serializable](val data: T)(implicit m: Manifest[T]) {
  override def toString = m.runtimeClass
}
val wrapper = new MyWrapper(value)
```

The problem is I need to return `java.lang.String` from a call of `toString`. But I got `java.io.Serializable`. Unfortunately I am neither able to create fixed pattern matching for each `java.io.Serializable` subtype (this would be crazy) nor to create `MyWrapper` explicit with `new MyWrapper[String](value)`. I don't know the type of `value`, maybe it is a subtype of `Serializable`.

Is there some way to pass type/manifest value at runtime if I know that value type is equal to variable `clazz`?

---

Update (solution from Régis Jean-Gilles don't work). REPL test:

```
val clazz: Class[_ <: java.io.Serializable] = classOf[java.lang.String]
val value: java.io.Serializable = "abc"

class MyWrapper[T <: java.io.Serializable](val data: T)(implicit m: Manifest[T]) {
  override def toString = m.runtimeClass.getName
}
val wrapper = new MyWrapper(value)
//val wrapper = new MyWrapper(value)(ClassManifest.fromClass(clazz).asInstanceOf[ClassTypeManifest[java.io.Serializable]])
//val wrapper = new MyWrapper(value)(ClassManifest.fromClass(clazz))
System.err.println(wrapper.toString)
```

I got an error, if I tried to pass manifest explicit:

```
scala> :load test.scala
Loading test.scala...
clazz: Class[_ <: java.io.Serializable] = class java.lang.String
value: java.io.Serializable = abc
defined class MyWrapper
<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.reflect.ClassManifest[_$1] where type _$1 <: java.io.Serializable
    (which expands to)  scala.reflect.ClassTag[_$1]
 required: Manifest[java.io.Serializable]
       val wrapper = new MyWrapper(value)(ClassManifest.fromClass(clazz))
                                                                 ^
<console>:8: error: not found: value wrapper
              System.err.println(wrapper.toString)
```

Also I am unable to cast manifest explicit.

There is more strange error when I try to compile my application -

```
[error]  found   : scala.reflect.ClassManifest[(some other)_0(in method setProperty)]
[error]     (which expands to)  scala.reflect.ClassTag[(some other)_0(in method setProperty)]
[error]  required: Manifest[_0(in method setProperty)]
[error]           new Value.Static(default, Context.virtual(element))(ClassManifest.fromClass(elementProperty.typeClass)))
```

IMHO Régis Jean-Gilles very very close to solution. How to make it work with Scala 2.10?

Comment: I am trying to do a similar thing today! As commented below, the generic types are erased at run-time. Did you find any viable solution or workaround?

Comment: Nope. Please look at http://dcsobral.blogspot.ru/2012/08/json-serialization-with-reflection-in.html (results at bottom) and https://github.com/aloiscochard/sherpa I suspect that it is right direction. Adjust such solution for my case is too complex. Also search for "typetag serialization"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are using manifests to work around type erasure but at a specific point all you have is a `Class[_]` so you need to convert it back to a manifest. Correct?

If so, you can use `ClassManifest.fromClass`, and then explicitly pass it as the implicit value `m`.

```
val wrapper = new MyWrapper(value)(Manifest.classType(clazz))
```

You should probably abstract it away:

```
object MyWrapper {
  def fromRuntimeType[T <: java.io.Serializable]( value: T ): MyWrapper[T] = {
    new MyWrapper(value)(Manifest.classType(value.getClass))
  }
}
```

Keep in mind though that because you only have a  `Class` instance in the first place, you are at the mercy of type erasure again. This means that if the class (that you need to get a manifest for) is generic, you won't have any type parameter information in the manifest returned by `ClassManifest.fromClass`.

Comment: Awesome. `new MyWrapper(value)(ClassManifest.fromClass(clazz))` is exactly what I want. Thank you very much.

Comment: :-( compilation failed with scala-2.10

Comment: Try with `val wrapper = new MyWrapper(value)(Manifest.classType(clazz))`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Yes. It works. Thank you. I misunderstand one thing: `new MyWrapper(value)(Manifest.classType(clazz))` fine, but `val m = Manifest.classType(clazz); val wrapper = new MyWrapper(value)(m)` not. It fail with _found : scala.reflect.Manifest[Nothing] required: Manifest[java.io.Serializable]_ Could you explain it? Or I need to create a bug at scala bugtracker.

Comment: This is actually normal. When a method has several parameter lists type inference flows from left to right, so when calling `MyWrapper`'s constructor, the type of the first argument `value`  allows to infer that T=Serializable. This is then used in the implicit parameter list and flows back to `Manifest.classType`, which is applied with T=Serializable. So classType returns `ClassManifest[Serializable]`. By contrast in `val m = Manifest.classType(clazz)` the compiler can't infer `T` (given how `classType` is declared to take a `Class[_]` instead of a `Class[T]`) so you get back `Class[Nothing]`

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't

```
override def toString = data.getClass.getName
```

already work for you? That yields `java.lang.String`.

Comment: data.getClass and m.runtimeClass maybe different in some cases

Comment: I may have from a deserialization framework the `clazz` with MyType and the `value` with MyRichTypeWithALotOf. If I just use data - I have subtype instead of type. Please remember - I have a DSL. There are constrains. Sometimes I have null as value (ok - None). What class of None at runtime?